# android in app purchase causes distribution limits

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Good day.

In my application I have paid items and for a long time I was accepting purchases through PayPal only. Recently I have added Google Inn App Purchases too. But the problem is, that when you add inn app purchases to the app your app disappears from the stores of lot of countries (about 60).
Google supports said that as they cannot support inn app billing in that countries they do not distribute apps with inn app billing to such countries. 
But for my app it is really bad, because I loose a lot of users.

So the question is - how can I keep inn app billing in my app for the countries that are supported and also distribute my app in the other countries without inn app billing.

The first solution that came to my mind is to create a totally different app in app store, but keeping the name of the app. But as I understand this way I have to change the namespace of my app, and that will cause me a lot of problems (I will have to create another facebook app for new namespace and a lot of such problems).

So may be somebody has other ideas how can I solve this problem?
Any kind of ideas are welcomed - even if you are not sure that they will work...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a beautiful solution, but I *think* it would work:

Keep your old package name, and remove the in-app purchases from it. We'll call this the "functional package".

Create a new package to handle *only* the in-app purchases (including the UI for it, I guess). We'll call this the "IAP package".

Unfortunately (and this is the not-so-beautiful part), this means that users who want to do the in-app purchases stuff will have to install both of these packages. I'm not sure if the install order matters.

Now, implement an interface between these two packages so that the functional package can ask the IAP package whether certain purchases have been done or not. An AIDL service is probably what you want here.

**Important**: Depending on your worry of piracy/cracking, you should make sure this interface is somewhat secure. At least put a permission limiting who can access it, and give that permission a protectionLevel of "signature". You may also want to add some logic to check that this permission is actually defined by the expected package, [and not someone else](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

You probably also want your two packages to have a shared userid, and maybe have the IAP package's components run in the functional package's process through the android:process attribute.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting idea! I will consider this as another way to solve my problem, and if at the end I will choose this solution I will let you know. But for now I will search and wait for some other ideas.

Comment: Good luck -- and I'd be interested to hear the results, no matter what strategy you choose!